# how to increase array element by multiplying

Tags: c#

Textbox2 has some 60 ids and i want to increase it to 250.... 
So i use following code increase the elements.
when i click the size button textbox2 should have 300 ids(now it has 60 only)..
lately i need to reduce it to 250 ids

. But it is getting exceptions

```
    private void Size_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] vlist = textBox1.Text.Split('\n');

        int size = (Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text)) / Convert.ToInt32(vlist) +1;
        int p = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text) * size;

        textBox2.Text = p.ToString();

    }
```

[image]

Please tell me what should i do in this?

Comment: `Convert.ToInt32(vlist)` Why are you converting a string array to an integer?

Comment: i need to multiply 60 ids . vlist in string format so i converted in to int

Comment: So, you want to multiply each line in your textbox1 by value in textbox2? Also, that does not explain why you convert string array. What you want is converting each string in the array and not the array itself.

Comment: i know my logic is wrong. I want to increase these 60 ids to 300 after that i need to reduce it to 250, please tell me the method

Comment: You want to increase the number of ID or the ID themselves? So, you have 60 lines in textbox1, when user put 300 in textbox2 and press Size button, you want to change it to 300 lines, then 250 in textbox2 and press Size button, change to 250 lines?

Comment: ID them selves... 60 ids should be printed 5 times again and again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void Size_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    List<string> vlist = new List<string>(textBox2.Text.Split('\n'));
    int currentLineNumber = vlist.Count;
    int targetLineNumber = Int32.Parse(textBox1.Text);

    if (targetLineNumber == currentLineNumber)
        return; //nothing to change
    else if (targetLineNumber > currentLineNumber) //increase number of line
    {
        for (int i = currentLineNumber; i < targetLineNumber; ++i)
            vlist.Add(vlist[(i - currentLineNumber) % currentLineNumber]);
    }
    else //reduce number of line
        vlist = vlist.GetRange(0, targetLineNumber);

    if (vlist.Count == 0)
        textBox2.Text = String.Empty;
    else
    {
        string result = vlist[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < targetLineNumber; ++i)
            result += String.Format("\n{0}", vlist[i]);
        textBox2.Text = result;
    }
}
```

The logic is quite simple. First, get number of line in textbox1 and target line number in textbox2. (This assume textbox1 is not empty though)

For increasing in size, we just keep adding id to the list until it reaches target size. For reducing size, it is even simpler, just take the first N lines from the list. After resizing, just reconnect all the lines together and set textBox1.Text to it.

Comment: there is an exception for this one

Comment: FormatExeption was unhand led in             int targetLineNumber = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);

Comment: Put a try catch block around it and please ensure Text in the smaller textbox is really number.

Comment: see this image [Please click here](https://scontent.fcmb2-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/25498102_154984081934010_2197442496510681894_n.jpg?oh=e3e208d0d0f98481e3bea8198a8c66b3&oe=5AC5AD3A)

Comment: I entered only 250

Comment: Change to Int32.Parse

Comment: hi . I think texbox numbers are not right of your code. textbox1 should be textbox2.textbox2 should be textbox3

Comment: Arh...TextBox2 is the big one.. Swap textBox1 and textBox2

Comment: Which is your job to modify the job to adapt. I can't control how you name your controls.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161584/discussion-between-user3398379-and-lamandy).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the array size.
If you want to have dynamic size you should use collections like `List<T>`

Comment: ok. But I want to increase these 60 ids to 300 after that i need to reduce it to 250, please tell me the method

Comment: tell me what you want to do?(your problem not your solution).
may be some one have better solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
...
    string[] vlist = textBox1.Text.Split('\n');
    int size = (Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text)) / Convert.ToInt32(vlist.Length) +1;
    string newString = "";
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
        newString = String.Join("\n",vlist);
        textBox2.Text += newString + "\n";
    }
...
```

This way, you append to the textbox the information you already got there (vlist), the number of times you need (size). I haven't tested it but probably this would repeat those IDs once more tan desired, in that case, remove the "+1" from the size variable definition

For the reduction to 250, you should specify which criteria are you following... if they are only the first 250, you could do that easily in a for loop with 250 as the break condition / top value

Comment: string doesn't contain definition for join

Comment: String.Join with uppercase, sorry

Comment: what's the error? I've realized this could raise an error, change `Convert.ToInt32(vlist)` to  `Convert.ToInt32(vlist.Length)`

Comment: take a look at the edits, I have tested it now and it works in my computer ;)